# Looping through a list with setTimeout inside returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I am implementing the setTimeout function inside 'for loop', which doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here's the codes I used:

```
var listItems = ['1','2','3'];

for(var i = 0 ; i < listItems.length ; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(listItems[i])
    },500)
}
```

Tested, returns 'Undefined (3)'

Baffled, tried another solution

```
var listItems = ['1','2','3'];
for(var i = 0 ; i < listItems.length ; i++){
    setTimeout(function(i){
      console.log(listItems[i])
    },500)
}
```

Obviously this wasn't even valid.

Looked on another similar question here, and tried:

```
var listItems = ['1','2','3'];
for(var i = 0 ; i < listItems.length ; i++){

    (function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(listItems[i])
      },500)
    })(i);

}
```

Still 'undefined(3)'

This is the working code without the setTimeout function. I am not sure what I am doing it wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Your last try seems to be the good one, you just forgot to declare the argument on the Self Invocation Function.


    (function(value){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(value)
      },500)
    })(listItems[i]);

Comment: @jonas, it does no explain the wrong use of the closure which does not have a parameter, but the inner function has one, but this in nerver used.

Comment: @nina so you want to add an answer for this: `(function(i){` ?! Then the OP hasnt read the explanations carefully.

Comment: i missed a comment for this, guided with closing

Comment: the problem is that `i` is locally scoped, you do not need all these closures, you can, in fact, just assign a new value your indexer, and leave your first example as-is.. i.e. `let n = i` .. and then `console.log(listItems[n])`

Comment: @Disfigure Tried it, and that seems to work. Thanks for the answer & explanation! I will look it up further.

Comment: @YongjuLee your answer can also be found in the duplicate question, pertinent to you, answer #4 (which is what i stated above)